# Can Tiny C compiler be used for OpenCV code compiling?

Tags: c, windows, opencv, tcc

I am new to OpenCV and I have only Tiny C compiler configured on my Windows XP machine. Can I use this tiny C compiler to compile opencv programs for image manipulations. I have alredy installed python2.6 and opencv2.0 on my windows xp pc. If we can compile how can we do that? I tried on net but found nothing of use. Please help.

**Edit:** If not possible in Tiny C compiler then please suggest any links for easily available opencv compatible c compilers for windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think try it.

If it doesn't work, the [OpenCV Install Guide](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide) says:

> C/C++ compiler (OpenCV is known to work with VS2005, VS2008,
>   including Express Editions, and MinGW on Windows, GCC 4.x on Linux, MacOSX and other Unix-like systems).

[Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/)

[MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/)

Comment: Thanks. I just found a guide on windows opencv setup http://tommy.chheng.com/development/windows_development_setup.html